# Unable to update entity as it has a definingQuery and no <InsertFunction>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Using entity framework trying to create a new product. For the sake of getting it to work I have added dummy values,4 ,4 ,4 bla, 123 etc, but it still wont allow me to add a new record whne it tries to save it gives me the error:

```
Unable to update the EntitySet 'HandHeld_Product' because it has a DefiningQuery and no <InsertFunction> element exists in the <ModificationFunctionMapping> element to support the current operation.
```

I have no idea why I have done this many times before with different products and lists etc...but never seen this error please advise?

```
using (EPOSEntities1 db = new EPOSEntities1())
            {
                foreach (Product product in Products)
                {
                    HandHeld_Product HH = new HandHeld_Product();
                    HH.Id = 4;// product.Id;
                    HH.ServerProductId = 4;// product.ServerProductId;
                    HH.Name = "bla";// product.Name;//should be description
                    HH.ItemBarcode = "123";// product.ItemBarcode;
                    HH.CaseBarcode = "123";// product.CaseBarcode;
                    HH.NumInItem = 123;// product.NumInItem;
                    HH.NumInCase = 123;// product.NumInCase;
                    HH.IsWeighableOnKegScales = true;// product.IsWeighableOnKegScales;
                    HH.IsWeighableOnSpiritScales = true;// product.IsWeighableOnSpiritScales;
                    HH.EmptyWeight = 123;// product.EmptyWeight;
                    HH.FullWeight = 123;//product.FullWeight;

                    db.AddToHandHeld_Product(HH);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that your database table doesn't have a primary key.